# How do i fix this into a json file?

Tags: json, formatting

So I have a Json file but I'm not sure if it is formatted correctly. At each "timestamp" there is a maximum of 4 events (on channels 1-4) that can happen and if 0 happen then the timestamp won't print at all. I will want to be able to call the "activity", "azimuth" and "elevation" values for each channel from each timestamp.

```css
 {
    "timeStamp": 1440,
    "unix": 1546907973091,
    "events": [
        { "id": 23, "channel": 1, "activity": 0.998, "azimuth": 66.330, "elevation": 47.769 },
        { "id": 20, "channel": 3, "activity": 0.994, "azimuth": 202.169, "elevation": 6.801 }
    ]
},

 {
    "timeStamp": 1448,
    "unix": 1546907973101,
    "events": [
        { "id": 23, "channel": 1, "activity": 0.000, "azimuth": 66.331, "elevation": 47.769 },
        { "id": 20, "channel": 3, "activity": 1.000, "azimuth": 202.166, "elevation": 6.801 }
    ]
}
```

If someone can quickly tell me what needs to be changed that would be great.

Comment: Perhaps you can give a better idea of what specific problem you think needs solving, and what your goal is, and how a Linting tool did not help you make your JSON well-formed, and how this relates to C++ or software in general?

Answer (score 1):

You should have an additional member, `events` to denote the events. Something like this:

```
"unix": 1546905049755,
"events": [
        { "id": 9, "channel": 1, "activity": 1.000, "azimuth": 227.523, "elevation": 10.411 },
        { "id": 3, "channel": 3, "activity": 0.000, "azimuth": 343.892, "elevation": 27.878 }
    ]
```

Also, remove `][` which is mentioned at some places in the file.

Final JSON:

```
[
    {
        "timeStamp": 1808,
        "unix": 1546905049755,
        "events": [
            { "id": 9, "channel": 1, "activity": 1.000, "azimuth": 227.523, "elevation": 10.411 },
            { "id": 3, "channel": 3, "activity": 0.000, "azimuth": 343.892, "elevation": 27.878 }
        ]
    },

    {
        "timeStamp": 1824,
        "unix": 1546905049769,
        "events": [
            { "id": 9, "channel": 1, "activity": 1.000, "azimuth": 227.527, "elevation": 10.436 },
            { "id": 3, "channel": 3, "activity": 0.000, "azimuth": 343.882, "elevation": 27.899 }
        ]
    },

    {
        "timeStamp": 1832,
        "unix": 1546905049777,
        "events": [
            { "id": 9, "channel": 1, "activity": 1.000, "azimuth": 227.528, "elevation": 10.457 },
            { "id": 3, "channel": 3, "activity": 0.000, "azimuth": 343.877, "elevation": 27.910 }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix several issues:

1. `"unix": 1546905049755 [` missed `, "events":` key
2. Array brackets are broken

This is the valid JSON most close to your one:

```
[
  {
        "timeStamp": 1808,
        "unix": 1546905049755,
        "events": [{
                "id": 9,
                "channel": 1,
                "activity": 1.000,
                "azimuth": 227.523,
                "elevation": 10.411
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "channel": 3,
                "activity": 0.000,
                "azimuth": 343.892,
                "elevation": 27.878
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "timeStamp": 1824,
        "unix": 1546905049769,
        "events": [{
                "id": 9,
                "channel": 1,
                "activity": 1.000,
                "azimuth": 227.527,
                "elevation": 10.436
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "channel": 3,
                "activity": 0.000,
                "azimuth": 343.882,
                "elevation": 27.899
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "timeStamp": 1832,
        "unix": 1546905049777,
        "events": [{
                "id": 9,
                "channel": 1,
                "activity": 1.000,
                "azimuth": 227.528,
                "elevation": 10.457
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "channel": 3,
                "activity": 0.000,
                "azimuth": 343.877,
                "elevation": 27.910
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

You can use [JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate any JSON

Comment: Great thank you, is it still valid without curly brackets (encapsulating the whole file) at the start and end? (such as my updated code)

Comment: @JakeDonovan-parker Please read the documentation, like at json.org. You'll see that the syntax allows an array to be at the top level. What reference are you using in your research at present?

Comment: The json file was already created by the open source program i am using, i just needed it formatted properly so i can call the elements of the arrays to use the values for other calculations.